# Python database connection and resultset into string

Tags: python, sql-server-2008, python-2.7, pyodbc

I'm almost finished with one script that will check a table and email the result of this one. Although I'm getting this error.

```
No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

This is what my script looks like.

```
import os
import sys
import pyodbc
import smtplib

# Set up mail info
FROM = "it@company.se"
TO = ["pd@company.se"] # must be a list
TEXT = "Dialer import status "
SUBJECT = "Dialer import status"

#Defining variables for script 
try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL  Server}
    ;SERVER=sesrv413;DATABASE=Maintenance;Trusted_Connection=yes')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    query = "Select status from dialer_import_status"
    rows =  cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
    TEXT = TEXT + str(row.status)

except:
# Send the mail
  server = smtplib.SMTP("email.intrum.net",25)
  message = "From:%s \nTo:%s \nSubject:%s 
  \n\n%s\n" %(FROM, ", ".join(TO),  SUBJECT, TEXT)
  server = smtplib.SMTP("email.company.net",25)
  server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
  server.quit()
  raise
```

Has anyone experience similar issues before? And how did you solve it?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

No query has been executed, because you forgot to call `cursor.execute(query)` before `cursor.fetchall()`.

Comment: do I need to import something to use execute? like Import pyodbc etc. I'm new to shell scripting

Comment: no, just call the method on the cursor object. I fixed my code